# Verbos HTTP en formularios HTML

Tags: html

¿Por qué motivo verbos HTTP como `PUT` o `DELETE` no estan disponibles en formularios HTML?

Comment: He visto la misma pregunta en StackExchange: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/211790

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En la especificación de la [W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#element-attrdef-form-method) indica que dentro de los atributos de la etiqueta `form` está:

- `method` acepta solo verbos `GET` y `POST`

Mientras que en el protocolo HTTP se indican los verbos que representan acciones específicas sobre los datos que manda o recibe el [servidor](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP)

Partimos entonces que no soporta dichas declaraciones de forma nativa teniendo solo 2 verbos para las acciones que se aplican a un grupo de datos.

Sin embargo verás que muchos frameworks backend dan soporte a la declaración del verbo a usar a través de directivas.

Por ejemplo en Laravel es:

```
method('verbo')
```

Sin embargo a nivel de atributos el `form` va a seguir requiriendo que identifiques solo a `GET` O `POST`

Te recomiendo leer sobre la especificación de  [HTTP](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5.1.1)  que cubre el tema de verbos o métodos  los cuales si tienen identificada de una forma más clara la acción que solicitarán se ejecute a la URL que apunta en uno o varios servidores