# Importancia de verbos HTTP

Tags: http, http-post

Quisiera saber por qué es importante definir correctamente los verbos GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, PATCH, etc si dentro de los métodos puedo realizar cualquier operación. Por ejemplo, en java podría definir un controlador con mapeo hacía un endpoint de la siguiente forma:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String createUser(@Valid User user, BindingResult result, Model model) {
        //creación del usuario
    }
```

Este controlador por dentro lo que hace es crear un usuario pero podría incluir código para que valide si el usuario ya existe, de ser así podría actualizar ese mismo registro. Según entiendo, en este caso el verbo http correcto sería usar PUT y no POST.

Si por favor podrían aclararme esa duda, se los agradecería.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Verbos HTTP en formularios HTML](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/321549/verbos-http-en-formularios-html)

Comment: Al margen de REST, hay una cosa que se llama `Principio de la mínima sorpresa`. Todo el mundo esperará que un `POST /create` sirva para **crear** algo, que `PUT /user125` se use para modificar un algo, y que `GET /user125` sirva para **obtener** ese algo.